# Inserting CSV into mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

this may just be the dumbest question I have asked yet. But I can not figure this out. I am trying to import a CSV into my mysql. But I can not get these areas correct:

Columns separated with:
Columns enclosed with:
Columns escaped with:
Lines terminated with:

Here is an example row in mycsv: 
AA|Armed Forces Americas|US|United States

what would I place in each one?

Comment: That's not a CSV per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have table that match the column configuration of the file what you do is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '<full file path>`
INTO TABLE <tbl_name>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

If some of the fields may contain `|` then these fields should be enclosed by `"` and then the last clause becomes:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY '\n'
```